# Auto embed youtube videos in app in android studio

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

How to add auto embed youtube playlist (when the video uploads in youtube it should appear the embedded video automatically in app) with iframe Youtube player and  custom css style in android studio but I'm unable to do it can you please help me in this ? I need it to upload without any updates in Google play ?

I tried single auto embed youtube but I do not want to write same code where I have to open android studio every time...help me in this..